# Copy each mp3 to folder "$artist - $album" and rename to "$TrackNr - $Title"

Tags: linux, bash, mp3

I want to tidy a big, unsorted folder of .mp3's. I'm sure there is an option to read the mp3-Tags and copy the files to where they belong, in Linux, right?

Answer (score 2):

The tool I maintain, [`audiotag`](http://github.com/Daenyth/audiotag), can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Though not really an so question...

```
sudo apt-get install tagtool
```

(if you are on debian/ubuntu derivative)

Answer (score 0):

There are many existing tools that do that. Ex-falso is one, thunar's bulk-rename is another, for example.